# how to see what menu item was clicked from Android.Gallery if I have two menu items

Tags: android, action

When you want to send an image to facebook from your device,
you open the `Android.Gallery` and select image and press share.

I see Facebook have two `Menu` items in the Share-List:
- facebook
- facebook for HTC Sence (in my phone HTC Desire)

If i want to have the same setup how is this done?

Registering for the `android.intent.action.SEND` in my activity
of course give me one `Menu` item. But i need two and handle them differently .

Comment: It was simple, I can have two activity's and handle each SEND :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have two activity's and each on having it's own SEND